# UIBarButtonItem with custom title

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *promoteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(promoteToInstagram:)];
    [promoteButton setTitle:@"Promote"];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = promoteButton;
```

I am trying to create a UIBarButtonItem with a custom title. Why does the above says cancel instead of Promote?

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct initializer, perhaps?

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem  btnSort = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Descending" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pressAscending)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:btnSort];
```